View wrap_content in not working in TableLayout
I add table rows with cells to a table dynamically.
The rows and cells are added, but the text in the cells do not wrap.
Part of code follows here:
Layout is as follows:
<TableLayout
          android:id="@+id/TableTheOpenQuestion"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
          android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
          android:backgroundTint="@color/backgroundColor"
          android:visibility="gone"
          android:stretchColumns="*">
      </TableLayout>

And the corresponding Java file where I use the above layout is as follows:

      tableLayout = findViewById(R.id.TableTheOpenQuestion);
      TableRow tr = new TableRow(dContext);
      TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1);
      params.setMargins(12, 0, 12, 0);
      tr.setLayoutParams(params);
      TableRow.LayoutParams cellParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

      TextView tv = new TextView(dContext);
      tv.setLayoutParams(cellParams);
      tv.setPadding(5, 10, 10, 10);
      tv.setText("A very long text.A very long text.A very long text.A very long text.A very long text.A very long text.A very long text.A very long text.");
      tr.addView(tv);

      //
      // Add the row to the table
      //
      tableLayout.addView(tr);

I have been searching a lot of similar questions, but nothing seems to work for me. All help greatly appreciated!

For the TextView, TableRow params should be as follows, instead of what you've written
TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                0, // Width 0 to allow wrapping
                TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, // Wrap content height
                1.0f // Equal weight for each cell
        );

And then you can assign the params to your TextView
TextView textView = new TextView(context);
textView.setText(text);
textView.setLayoutParams(params);


Could you mark the answer as solved, so that it helps others

sorry, forgot. the green tick is it?
